# NetBIOS name of Web Application

Tags: kerberos, host-header

This may be a no brainier to some, but i'm stumped and can't get a straight answer as to what the netBIOS name of a web application would be. Is it the same as my host header i created for the web application?

The reason i ask is because when i setup my SPN's for Kerberos I used the FQDN instead of the NETBIOS names and i'm trying to wrap my head around what would be correct.

Example:

In the entry below:

http://intranet.mycompany.com- would the netBIOS name be "intranet"

for Central Admin:

http://*servername*:55555- would the netBIOS name  be "ServerName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, technically the NetBIOS name (really, hostname) would be "intranet" and "servername" as you've pointed out.  You don't *have* to have a NetBIOS name, if you only use FQDNs.

Comment: Much appreciated Trevor, that confirms my hunch. Cheers!